# Why does my USB wireless network adapter disconnect every few seconds?

Tags: wifi, networking, drivers

I don't have experience with drivers and other things. After installing Linux Mint 11 on my machine (I did a dist-upgrade), everything seemed to be great -- I didn't need to install any drivers. After a while I realized that my connection would stop after a few minutes (it shows that I'm connected but I'm not), so I need to reconnect. After a few minutes, it disconnects again.

I'm using an Alfa USB wireless adapter AWS036H. I think the driver I'm using is Realtek

---

These are some outputs of a few things people usually ask for. Note: I'm NOT using a laptop.

#### dmsg

```
[19445.604448] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=00:c0:ca:44:62:d1:00:24:c8:4b:46:e0:08:00 SRC=2.174.220.77 DST=192.168.1.6 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=104 ID=10466 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=55150 DPT=6881 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
[19448.164050] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=00:c0:ca:44:62:d1:00:24:c8:4b:46:e0:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=192.168.1.6 LEN=56 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=41982 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=3 CODE=0 [SRC=192.168.1.6 DST=91.189.88.33 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=7566 DF PROTO=TCP INCOMPLETE [8 bytes] ] 
[19465.079565] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=00:c0:ca:44:62:d1:00:24:c8:4b:46:e0:08:00 SRC=80.128.216.31 DST=192.168.1.6 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=113 ID=5100 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=50169 DPT=6881 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
[19486.270328] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=00:c0:ca:44:62:d1:00:24:c8:4b:46:e0:08:00 SRC=90.130.13.122 DST=192.168.1.6 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=109 ID=22207 PROTO=UDP SPT=6881 DPT=6881 LEN=28 
[19497.480522] wlan0: deauthenticating from 00:24:c8:4b:46:e0 by local choice (reason=3)
[19497.593276] cfg80211: All devices are disconnected, going to restore regulatory settings
[19497.593282] cfg80211: Restoring regulatory settings
[19497.593346] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[19497.638740] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2412 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[19497.638745] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[19497.638749] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2417 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[19497.638753] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[19497.638756] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2422 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[19497.638760] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[19497.638763] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2427 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[19497.638766] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[19497.638770] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2432 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[19497.638773] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[19497.638776] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2437 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[19497.638780] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[19497.638783] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2442 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[19497.638787] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[19497.638790] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2447 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[19497.638794] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[19497.638797] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2452 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[19497.638801] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[19497.638804] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2457 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[19497.638807] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[19497.638811] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2462 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[19497.638814] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[19497.638817] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2467 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[19497.638821] cfg80211: 2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[19497.638824] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2472 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[19497.638828] cfg80211: 2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[19497.638831] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2484 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[19497.638835] cfg80211: 2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[19497.638838] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[19497.638841] cfg80211:     (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[19497.638845] cfg80211:     (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[19497.638848] cfg80211:     (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[19497.638852] cfg80211:     (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[19497.638855] cfg80211:     (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[19497.638859] cfg80211:     (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[19513.145150] wlan0: authenticate with 00:24:c8:4b:46:e0 (try 1)
[19513.146910] wlan0: authenticated
[19513.252775] wlan0: associate with 00:24:c8:4b:46:e0 (try 1)
[19513.255149] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 00:24:c8:4b:46:e0 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[19513.255154] wlan0: associated
[19515.675091] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=00:c0:ca:44:62:d1:00:24:c8:4b:46:e0:08:00 SRC=91.79.8.40 DST=192.168.1.6 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x20 TTL=110 ID=42720 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=1945 DPT=6881 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
[19525.684312] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=00:c0:ca:44:62:d1:00:24:c8:4b:46:e0:08:00 SRC=78.13.80.169 DST=192.168.1.6 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=109 ID=49890 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=53401 DPT=6881 WINDOW=16384 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
[19551.856766] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=00:c0:ca:44:62:d1:00:24:c8:4b:46:e0:08:00 SRC=85.228.39.93 DST=192.168.1.6 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=103 ID=1162 PROTO=UDP SPT=6881 DPT=6881 LEN=28 
[19564.623005] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=00:c0:ca:44:62:d1:00:24:c8:4b:46:e0:08:00 SRC=90.202.21.238 DST=192.168.1.6 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=114 ID=17881 PROTO=UDP SPT=6881 DPT=6881 LEN=28 
[19584.855364] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=00:c0:ca:44:62:d1:00:24:c8:4b:46:e0:08:00 SRC=2.49.151.87 DST=192.168.1.6 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=117 ID=31716 PROTO=UDP SPT=6881 DPT=6881 LEN=28 
[19604.688647] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=00:c0:ca:44:62:d1:00:24:c8:4b:46:e0:08:00 SRC=109.225.124.155 DST=192.168.1.6 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=112 ID=6656 PROTO=UDP SPT=6881 DPT=6881 LEN=28 
[19626.362529] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=00:c0:ca:44:62:d1:00:24:c8:4b:46:e0:08:00 SRC=81.184.50.41 DST=192.168.1.6 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=114 ID=23241 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=1416 DPT=6881 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
[19645.040906] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=00:c0:ca:44:62:d1:00:24:c8:4b:46:e0:08:00 SRC=92.250.245.244 DST=192.168.1.6 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=51 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=50061 DPT=6881 WINDOW=16384 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
[19665.212659] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=00:c0:ca:44:62:d1:00:24:c8:4b:46:e0:08:00 SRC=87.183.3.18 DST=192.168.1.6 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=111 ID=1689 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=62817 DPT=6881 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
[19685.036415] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=00:c0:ca:44:62:d1:00:24:c8:4b:46:e0:08:00 SRC=78.13.80.169 DST=192.168.1.6 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=109 ID=50638 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=49624 DPT=6881 WINDOW=16384 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
[19705.487915] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=00:c0:ca:44:62:d1:00:24:c8:4b:46:e0:08:00 SRC=217.122.17.82 DST=192.168.1.6 LEN=56 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=112 ID=19070 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=54795 DPT=6881 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
[19726.779185] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=00:c0:ca:44:62:d1:00:24:c8:4b:46:e0:08:00 SRC=80.88.116.239 DST=192.168.1.6 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=109 ID=32168 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=57330 DPT=6881 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
[19744.755673] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=00:c0:ca:44:62:d1:00:24:c8:4b:46:e0:08:00 SRC=109.124.5.43 DST=192.168.1.6 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=113 ID=2288 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=6475 DPT=6881 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
[19764.449183] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=00:c0:ca:44:62:d1:00:24:c8:4b:46:e0:08:00 SRC=79.216.35.19 DST=192.168.1.6 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=113 ID=4281 PROTO=UDP SPT=6881 DPT=6881 LEN=28 
[19784.456189] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=00:c0:ca:44:62:d1:00:24:c8:4b:46:e0:08:00 SRC=81.82.25.149 DST=192.168.1.6 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=114 ID=1866 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=59507 DPT=6881 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
[19804.836687] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=00:c0:ca:44:62:d1:00:24:c8:4b:46:e0:08:00 SRC=81.56.199.3 DST=192.168.1.6 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=108 ID=14749 PROTO=UDP SPT=6881 DPT=6881 LEN=28 
[19824.812685] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=00:c0:ca:44:62:d1:00:24:c8:4b:46:e0:08:00 SRC=186.28.7.159 DST=192.168.1.6 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=107 ID=44686 PROTO=UDP SPT=23418 DPT=6881 LEN=28 
[19847.683314] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=00:c0:ca:44:62:d1:00:24:c8:4b:46:e0:08:00 SRC=78.13.80.169 DST=192.168.1.6 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=108 ID=63046 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=52192 DPT=6881 WINDOW=16384 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
[19884.711455] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=00:c0:ca:44:62:d1:00:24:c8:4b:46:e0:08:00 SRC=84.146.24.238 DST=192.168.1.6 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=113 ID=27914 PROTO=UDP SPT=6881 DPT=6881 LEN=28 
[19884.983589] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=00:c0:ca:44:62:d1:00:24:c8:4b:46:e0:08:00 SRC=2.107.130.61 DST=192.168.1.6 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=112 ID=7742 PROTO=UDP SPT=6881 DPT=6881 LEN=28 
[19905.681078] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=00:c0:ca:44:62:d1:00:24:c8:4b:46:e0:08:00 SRC=95.21.11.121 DST=192.168.1.6 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=114 ID=31775 PROTO=UDP SPT=6881 DPT=6881 LEN=28 
[19926.035707] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=00:c0:ca:44:62:d1:00:24:c8:4b:46:e0:08:00 SRC=109.76.132.55 DST=192.168.1.6 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=113 ID=28140 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=51905 DPT=6881 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
[19945.668326] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=00:c0:ca:44:62:d1:00:24:c8:4b:46:e0:08:00 SRC=188.92.0.197 DST=192.168.1.6 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=113 ID=7865 PROTO=UDP SPT=6881 DPT=6881 LEN=28 
[19967.200339] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=00:c0:ca:44:62:d1:00:24:c8:4b:46:e0:08:00 SRC=83.252.102.172 DST=192.168.1.6 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=105 ID=28408 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=63505 DPT=6881 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
[19999.752732] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=00:c0:ca:44:62:d1:00:24:c8:4b:46:e0:08:00 SRC=79.166.171.200 DST=192.168.1.6 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=110 ID=36405 PROTO=UDP SPT=6881 DPT=6881 LEN=28 
[20007.928719] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=00:c0:ca:44:62:d1:00:24:c8:4b:46:e0:08:00 SRC=79.235.59.16 DST=192.168.1.6 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=112 ID=46415 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=4537 DPT=6881 WINDOW=16384 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
[20026.181726] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=00:c0:ca:44:62:d1:00:24:c8:4b:46:e0:08:00 SRC=81.182.169.36 DST=192.168.1.6 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=106 ID=25126 PROTO=UDP SPT=6881 DPT=6881 LEN=28 
[20048.845358] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=00:c0:ca:44:62:d1:00:24:c8:4b:46:e0:08:00 SRC=87.66.118.104 DST=192.168.1.6 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=111 ID=18068 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=49928 DPT=6881 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
[20064.341857] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=00:c0:ca:44:62:d1:00:24:c8:4b:46:e0:08:00 SRC=77.2.63.153 DST=192.168.1.6 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=107 ID=7242 PROTO=UDP SPT=6881 DPT=6881 LEN=28 
[20090.093490] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=00:c0:ca:44:62:d1:00:24:c8:4b:46:e0:08:00 SRC=93.16.17.210 DST=192.168.1.6 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=108 ID=894 PROTO=UDP SPT=6881 DPT=6881 LEN=28 
[20104.443995] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=00:c0:ca:44:62:d1:00:24:c8:4b:46:e0:08:00 SRC=89.83.235.99 DST=192.168.1.6 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=114 ID=17295 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=58979 DPT=6881 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
[20128.625374] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=00:c0:ca:44:62:d1:00:24:c8:4b:46:e0:08:00 SRC=81.62.91.79 DST=192.168.1.6 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=107 ID=21793 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=51446 DPT=6881 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
[20151.055506] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=00:c0:ca:44:62:d1:00:24:c8:4b:46:e0:08:00 SRC=84.135.217.213 DST=192.168.1.6 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=112 ID=32452 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=55136 DPT=6881 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
[20164.618874] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=00:c0:ca:44:62:d1:00:24:c8:4b:46:e0:08:00 SRC=91.79.8.40 DST=192.168.1.6 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x20 TTL=110 ID=47784 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=2422 DPT=6881 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
[20184.337745] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=00:c0:ca:44:62:d1:00:24:c8:4b:46:e0:08:00 SRC=83.252.212.71 DST=192.168.1.6 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=107 ID=14544 PROTO=UDP SPT=6881 DPT=6881 LEN=28 
[20205.007512] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=00:c0:ca:44:62:d1:00:24:c8:4b:46:e0:08:00 SRC=91.62.158.247 DST=192.168.1.6 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=110 ID=21562 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=3933 DPT=6881 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
[20225.204018] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=00:c0:ca:44:62:d1:00:24:c8:4b:46:e0:08:00 SRC=84.146.24.238 DST=192.168.1.6 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=113 ID=15045 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=49630 DPT=6881 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
[20244.842290] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=00:c0:ca:44:62:d1:00:24:c8:4b:46:e0:08:00 SRC=82.82.190.168 DST=192.168.1.6 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=112 ID=23741 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=50766 DPT=6881 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
[20266.701649] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=00:c0:ca:44:62:d1:00:24:c8:4b:46:e0:08:00 SRC=88.153.108.124 DST=192.168.1.6 LEN=48 TOS=0x02 PREC=0x00 TTL=111 ID=206 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=2451 DPT=6881 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
[20286.305414] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=00:c0:ca:44:62:d1:00:24:c8:4b:46:e0:08:00 SRC=78.240.86.73 DST=192.168.1.6 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=107 ID=325 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=65184 DPT=6881 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
[    20294.293989] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=00:c0:ca:44:62:d1:00:24:c8:4b:46:e0:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=192.168.1.6 LEN=56 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=43133 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=3 CODE=0 [SRC=192.168.1.6 DST=91.189.88.33 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=56899 DF PROTO=TCP INCOMPLETE [8 bytes] ] 
[20294.297015] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=00:c0:ca:44:62:d1:00:24:c8:4b:46:e0:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=192.168.1.6 LEN=56 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=43134 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=3 CODE=0 [SRC=192.168.1.6 DST=91.189.88.40 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=12080 DF PROTO=TCP INCOMPLETE [8 bytes] ] 
[20294.297242] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=00:c0:ca:44:62:d1:00:24:c8:4b:46:e0:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=192.168.1.6 LEN=56 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=43135 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=3 CODE=0 [SRC=192.168.1.6 DST=91.189.88.33 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=25195 DF PROTO=TCP INCOMPLETE [8 bytes] ] 
[20295.478338] wlan0: deauthenticating from 00:24:c8:4b:46:e0 by local choice (reason=3)
[20295.552735] cfg80211: All devices are disconnected, going to restore regulatory settings
[20295.552742] cfg80211: Restoring regulatory settings
[20295.552748] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[20295.680635] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2412 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[20295.680641] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[20295.680644] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2417 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[20295.680648] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[20295.680652] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2422 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[20295.680655] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[20295.680658] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2427 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[20295.680662] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[20295.680665] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2432 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[20295.680669] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[20295.680672] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2437 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[20295.680676] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[20295.680679] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2442 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[20295.680683] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[20295.680687] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2447 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[20295.680690] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[20295.680693] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2452 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[20295.680697] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[20295.680700] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2457 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[20295.680704] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[20295.680708] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2462 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[20295.680711] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[20295.680715] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2467 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[20295.680718] cfg80211: 2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[20295.680722] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2472 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[20295.680725] cfg80211: 2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[20295.680728] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2484 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[20295.680732] cfg80211: 2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[20295.680736] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[20295.680738] cfg80211:     (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[20295.680742] cfg80211:     (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[20295.680745] cfg80211:     (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[20295.680749] cfg80211:     (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[20295.680752] cfg80211:     (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[20295.680756] cfg80211:     (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[20306.009341] wlan0: authenticate with 00:24:c8:4b:46:e0 (try 1)
[20306.011225] wlan0: authenticated
[20306.118095] wlan0: associate with 00:24:c8:4b:46:e0 (try 1)
[20306.120963] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 00:24:c8:4b:46:e0 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[20306.120967] wlan0: associated
[20307.364427] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=00:c0:ca:44:62:d1:00:24:c8:4b:46:e0:08:00 SRC=87.91.101.130 DST=192.168.1.6 LEN=64 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=49 ID=36839 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=62492 DPT=6881 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
[20310.914290] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=00:c0:ca:44:62:d1:00:24:c8:4b:46:e0:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=192.168.1.6 LEN=56 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=43180 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=3 CODE=0 [SRC=192.168.1.6 DST=91.189.88.33 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=56900 DF PROTO=TCP INCOMPLETE [8 bytes] ] 
[20310.936634] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=00:c0:ca:44:62:d1:00:24:c8:4b:46:e0:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=192.168.1.6 LEN=56 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=43181 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=3 CODE=0 [SRC=192.168.1.6 DST=91.189.88.40 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=12081 DF PROTO=TCP INCOMPLETE [8 bytes] ] 
[20310.939017] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=00:c0:ca:44:62:d1:00:24:c8:4b:46:e0:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=192.168.1.6 LEN=56 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=43182 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=3 CODE=0 [SRC=192.168.1.6 DST=91.189.88.33 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=25196 DF PROTO=TCP INCOMPLETE [8 bytes] ] 
[20325.941050] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=00:c0:ca:44:62:d1:00:24:c8:4b:46:e0:08:00 SRC=217.118.78.99 DST=192.168.1.6 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=113 ID=4407 PROTO=UDP SPT=2970 DPT=6881 LEN=28 
[20328.801724] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=00:c0:ca:44:62:d1:00:24:c8:4b:46:e0:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.254 DST=192.168.1.6 LEN=56 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=43196 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=3 CODE=0 [SRC=192.168.1.6 DST=91.189.88.33 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=56901 DF PROTO=TCP INCOMPLETE [8 bytes] ]
```

#### inxi -N

```
Network:   Card-1 Realtek RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller driver r8169
           Card-2 Realtek RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+ driver 8139too
```

#### /usr/lib/linuxmint/mintWifi/mintWifi.py

```
 -------------------------
* I. scanning WIFI PCI devices...
-------------------------
* II. querying ndiswrapper...
-------------------------
* III. querying iwconfig...
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

eth1      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:"Home"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 00:24:C8:4B:46:E0   
          Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=68/70  Signal level=-42 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:1132   Missed beacon:0

-------------------------
* IV. querying ifconfig...
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1f:d0:c9:b8:8e  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:43 Base address:0x4000 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0e:2e:77:88:16  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:19 Base address:0xd000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:10696 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10696 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:3823011 (3.8 MB)  TX bytes:3823011 (3.8 MB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:c0:ca:44:62:d1  
          inet addr:192.168.1.6  Bcast:255.255.255.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2c0:caff:fe44:62d1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:90424 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:65201 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:98024465 (98.0 MB)  TX bytes:10345450 (10.3 MB)

-------------------------
* V. querying DHCP...
```

#### lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 82G33/G31/P35/P31 Express DRAM Controller (rev 10)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82G33/G31/P35/P31 Express PCI Express Root Port (rev 10)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 01)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 2 (rev 01)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 01)
00:1d.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 01)
00:1d.2 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 01)
00:1d.3 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 01)
00:1d.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 01)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev e1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GB/GR (ICH7 Family) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 01)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation N10/ICH7 Family SATA IDE Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family SMBus Controller (rev 01)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation G96 [GeForce 9400 GT] (rev a1)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 02)
04:01.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+ (rev 10)
```

#### lsmod

```
Module                  Size  Used by
ipt_REJECT             12512  1 
ipt_LOG                12784  5 
xt_limit               12541  7 
xt_tcpudp              12531  8 
ipt_addrtype           12535  4 
xt_state               12514  7 
ip6table_filter        12711  1 
ip6_tables             22545  1 ip6table_filter
nf_nat_irc             12542  0 
nf_conntrack_irc       13138  1 nf_nat_irc
nf_nat_ftp             12548  0 
nf_nat                 24827  2 nf_nat_irc,nf_nat_ftp
nf_conntrack_ipv4      19024  9 nf_nat
nf_defrag_ipv4         12649  1 nf_conntrack_ipv4
nf_conntrack_ftp       13106  1 nf_nat_ftp
nf_conntrack           69744  7 xt_state,nf_nat_irc,nf_conntrack_irc,nf_nat_ftp,nf_nat,nf_conntrack_ipv4,nf_conntrack_ftp
iptable_filter         12706  1 
i    p_tables              18125  1 iptable_filter
x_tables               21907  10 ipt_REJECT,ipt_LOG,xt_limit,xt_tcpudp,ipt_addrtype,xt_state,ip6table_filter,ip6_tables,iptable_filter,ip_tables
nls_utf8               12493  10 
udf                    83795  1 
crc_itu_t              12627  1 udf
usb_storage            43946  1 
uas                    17676  0 
snd_seq_dummy          12686  0 
cryptd                 19801  0 
aes_i586               16956  1 
aes_generic            38023  1 aes_i586
binfmt_misc            13213  1 
dm_crypt               22463  0 
vesafb                 13449  1 
nvidia               9766978  44 
arc4                   12473  2 
rtl8187                56206  0 
mac80211              257001  1 rtl8187
cfg80211              156212  2 rtl8187,mac80211
ppdev                  12849  0 
snd_hda_codec_realtek   255882  1 
parport_pc             32111  1 
psmouse                73312  0 
eeprom_93cx6           12653  1 rtl8187
snd_hda_intel          24113  5 
snd_hda_codec          90901  2 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13274  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                80042  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd_seq_midi           13132  0 
snd_rawmidi            25269  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14475  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                51291  3 snd_seq_dummy,snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_timer              28659  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14110  4 snd_seq_dummy,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
joydev                 17322  0 
snd                    55295  18 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
serio_raw              12990  0 
soundcore              12600  1 snd
snd_page_alloc         14073  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
lp                     13349  0 
parport                36746  3 ppdev,parport_pc,lp
usbhid                 41704  0 
hid                    77084  1 usbhid
dm_raid45              88410  0 
xor                    21860  1 dm_raid45
btrfs                 527388  0 
zlib_deflate           26594  1 btrfs
libcrc32c              12543  1 btrfs
8139too                23208  0 
8139cp                 22497  0 
r8169                  42534  0 
floppy                 60032  0
```

Comment: Looks like you're using the `rtl8187` driver included in the kernel. Looks like there's an `rtl8187se` driver in /staging that might work.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by installing RTL8187L driver and loading it.

I used this tutorial (it is for RTL8187 and R8187):
[here](http://forum.aircrack-ng.org/index.php?action=printpage;topic=5755.0)
That tutorial is perfect, but I still have problems with the new driver.

Answer (score 0):

I had this [a similar thing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1969/unexplained-log-cruft-and-possible-dropped-packets-on-wpa2-personal-lan) happen to my Linksys wusb100v2 (driver rt2870sta from Ralink). At first, it would randomly drop packets, then later it started to time out while waiting for a DHCP lease, then it would just sit there while the USB port registered then unregistered the device a few seconds later ad infinitum.

I eventually got curious and opened up the case to find that one of the diodes on the PCB had melted into a tiny lump of solder. I had to buy a new one.

The warranty was already expired on mine, so I had no qualms about opening it, but if yours is still good, I'd take advantage of it and get it replaced.