# Wireless rtl8187 freezes intermittently

Tags: networking, wifi

I am using a wireless USB ALFA 036H. Linux Mint (32-bit) recognizes it without any drivers but it stops downloading/uploading and I have to reconnect to get it to work again.

I tried to find a solution so I installed a different driver (the one I was supposed to use) and the problem changed: it stops downloading/uploading for few seconds (3-10) then just move on and start downloading/uploading again.
Any ideas?

More info:

- Linux Mint 32-bit
- device: ALFA AWUS036H USB wireless Adapter, 802.11g High power
- driver: rtl8187

Note: feel free to ask for more information.

lsmod output:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
rtl8187                56206  0 
mac80211              257001  1 rtl8187
cfg80211              156212  2 rtl8187,mac80211
eeprom_93cx6           12653  1 rtl8187
snd_seq_dummy          12686  0 
cryptd                 19801  0 
aes_i586               16956  1 
aes_generic            38023  1 aes_i586
arc4                   12473  2 
binfmt_misc            13213  1 
dm_crypt               22463  0 
vesafb                 13449  1 
nvidia               9766978  50 
snd_hda_codec_realtek   255882  1 
ipt_REJECT             12512  1 
ipt_LOG                12784  4 
snd_hda_intel          24113  5 
snd_hda_codec          90901  2 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13274  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                80042  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd_seq_midi           13132  0 
snd_rawmidi            25269  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14475  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                51291  3 snd_seq_dummy,snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_timer              28659  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14110  4 snd_seq_dummy,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
ppdev                  12849  0 
xt_limit               12541  6 
xt_tcpudp              12531  8 
ipt_addrtype           12535  4 
snd                    55295  18 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
parport_pc             32111  1 
xt_state               12514  9 
joydev                 17322  0 
ip6table_filter        12711  1 
psmouse                73312  0 
ip6_tables             22545  1 ip6table_filter
nf_nat_irc             12542  0 
nf_conntrack_irc       13138  1 nf_nat_irc
nf_nat_ftp             12548  0 
nf_nat                 24827  2 nf_nat_irc,nf_nat_ftp
nf_conntrack_ipv4      19024  11 nf_nat
nf_defrag_ipv4         12649  1 nf_conntrack_ipv4
nf_conntrack_ftp       13106  1 nf_nat_ftp
nf_conntrack           69744  7 xt_state,nf_nat_irc,nf_conntrack_irc,nf_nat_ftp,nf_nat,nf_conntrack_ipv4,nf_conntrack_ftp
iptable_filter         12706  1 
ip_tables              18125  1 iptable_filter
soundcore              12600  1 snd
x_tables               21907  10 ipt_REJECT,ipt_LOG,xt_limit,xt_tcpudp,ipt_addrtype,xt_state,ip6table_filter,ip6_tables,iptable_filter,ip_tables
snd_page_alloc         14073  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
serio_raw              12990  0 
lp                     13349  0 
parport                36746  3 ppdev,parport_pc,lp
usbhid                 41704  0 
hid                    77084  1 usbhid
dm_raid45              88410  0 
xor                    21860  1 dm_raid45
btrfs                 527388  0 
zlib_deflate           26594  1 btrfs
libcrc32c              12543  1 btrfs
8139too                23208  0 
8139cp                 22497  0 
floppy                 60032  0 
r8169                  42534  0
```

Comment: What do the system logs say, if anything?

Comment: I have the same problem with the same model.  I'm running Slackware 13.1, with Linux 2.6.35.4, my own configuration. I'll try the wireless gizmo again, to see what log messages I get.

Comment: So you solved http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24973/why-does-my-usb-wireless-network-adapter-disconnect-every-few-seconds by installing a different driver? Can you post that as an answer if so?

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Same driver as previous question [see lsmod output].

Comment: I've got a similar problem with CentOS 6.3! Everything seems to be right and then PUM! it can't connect by itself, I have to manually reconnect and then everything seems good for a few minutes and then the same again